# httpwebrequet for https fails with "The system cannot find the file specified exception"

Tags: c#, https, httpwebrequest, x509certificate

I am creating an "httpWebRequest"with following code

```
System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
HttpWebRequest request =  (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "GET";
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += CustomServiceCertificateValidation;
X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2("Client.cer");
request.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCertificate);
```

CustomServiceCertificateValidation function

```
private static bool CustomServiceCertificateValidation(
                object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain,
                SslPolicyErrors error)
{
     return true;
}
```

when I call

```
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

I get "The system cannot find the file specified exception".
Following trace I got it

```
at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._QueryCertFileType(String fileName)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromFile(String fileName, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName)
   at Transport.SendOut.CustomServiceCertificateValidation(Object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors error)
   at System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.Invoke(Object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
   at System.Net.ServerCertValidationCallback.Callback(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.ServerCertValidationCallback.Invoke(Object request, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.VerifyRemoteCertificate(RemoteCertValidationCallback remoteCertValidationCallback)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CompleteHandshake()
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
```

using Command
"openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:portno"

able to connect and return the server certificate.

In browser, I am able to access the same URL.

Please some one help me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like it can't find the file "client.cer". Make sure that the file is in the application's current working directory. Add this code above what you've posted:

```
if (!System.IO.File.Exists("client.cer"))
{
    throw new FileNotFoundException();
}
```

You either need to put the file in the application's working directory, or supply a path so that the system can find it.

You should put a `try ... catch` around your call to `request.GetResponse()` and examine the exception. I assume you're getting `FileNotFoundException`. According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filenotfoundexception(v=vs.110).aspx), the `FileName` property will tell you which file it was trying to read. So:

```
try
{
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException fex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to find file " + fex.FileName);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Some other exception.");
}
```

In the debugger, put breakpoints inside both of the `catch` clauses and examine the exception. That should tell you what file it's trying to find.

Comment: I tried providing complete file path like "C:\\client.cer" Still failed with the same exception.  
If you see the trace above, ServerCertValidationCallback() got called. Does that meat it's looking for Server certificate not client.cer?

Comment: @user3231632: See my update about how to catch and examine the exception.

Comment: Hi @user3231632, After adding pfx file to windows certificate store, http webrequest is able to get the response from the server.